# $G$ is dihedral group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be defined as all formal symbols $x^iy^j, \ i=0,1, j=0,1,\dots,n-1$ where we assume $$x^iy^j=x^{i'}y^{j'} \quad\text{if and only if}\quad  i=i', j=j'$$
$$x^2=y^n=e, \ n>2$$
$$xy=y^{-1}x$$

(a) Find the form of the product $(x^iy^j)(x^ky^l)$ as $x^{\alpha}y^{\beta}$.

(b) Using this, prove that $G$ is a non-abelian group of order $2n$.

**My efforts:** The set $G$ (not yet a group!) has $2n$ elements and using the first property it is obvious that all these elements are distinct. Thus $|G|=2n$.

1) In order to prove that $xy^j=y^{-j}x$ we should know that $y^{j}y^{k}=y^{j+k}=y^{j+k-n}$ is true and the analogous relation for $x^{i}$.

2) How to prove that $x^0=y^0=x^0y^0=e$?

3) Why $e$ is an identity element i.e. commutes with any element in $G$?

I have worked out on these questions but no results since $G$ is not yet a group, we should show that $G$ is a group.

Can anyone show that?

**P.S.** I know that the geometric interpretation of element of $G$ is reflection and rotations but I would like to derive needed relations via algebraic path. Please help with that.

Comment: Just to highlight some of the lack of rigour in your question statement, assumption 2 says that $x^2 = y^n = e$, but none of those three symbols are part of our set $G$, so that doesn't tell us anything. We haven't been told what the (supposed) group operation is either. There are lots of assumptions we can make about what the original question authour _meant_, and most of those assumptions will probably be true. But that doesn't mean that it's right to make them.

Comment: @Arthur, Indeed, you are definitely right! How to correct that?

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same thing. the way you have defined $G$, even $x$ and $y$ are not elements. You would have to define $x$ to be $x^1y^0$ and $y$ to be $x^0y^1$. If you are defining a group as a set of formal symbols, then you need to define the group operation on those symbols.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I am totally agree and that's why I have created this post. This is a problem from Herstein's book. I am going to understand the structure of  dihedral group and that's why I am asking these questions.

Comment: Do not downvote this topic. I am asking the problem from my algebra book. And it is not my fault that the text of problem is quite unclear.

Comment: @DerekHolt, could you show how to correct these unclear moments of my problem? It would be great

Comment: Something like: Suppose that $x,y \in G$ and that $|G|=2n$ with $G =\{ x^iy^j \mid 0\le i < 2,\,0 \le j < n \}$, where $x^2=y^n=1$ and $xy=y^{-1}x$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, $x^2, y^n, e$ do not lie in $G$. I think that you should add something else

Comment: @DerekHolt, Your definition of $G$ is the same as in my topic.

Comment: I am just using standard notation, where $1$ denotes the identity element - use $e$ if you prefer. The problem with your formulation is that it, appears to be redefining the standard meaning of $x^iy^j$ by referring to this as a "formal symbol".

Comment: @DerekHolt, If I understood correctly the flaw in my statement is the word "formal symbol", right? If we give to xiyjxiyj regular algebraic meaning it will be correct, right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use induction on $j$ to prove  *directly* that $xy^j=y^{-j}x$.

Indeed, it is the last assumption for $j=1$.
Now, if $j>1$,
\begin{align}
xy^j&=(xy)y^{j-1}=(y^{-1}x)y^{j-1}= y^{-1}(xy^{j-1})\\
&=y^{-1}(y^{1-j}x)\qquad\qquad\text{by the inductive hypothesis}\\
&=(y^{-1}y^{1-j})x=y^{-1+1-j}x=y^{-j}x.
\end{align}
2) There's nothing to prove: it's a convention that $x^0=y^0=e$.

3) Same answer: the rules which define the composition law on $G$ are just rewrite rules for formal symbols. They allow for simplifying expressions in $x$ and $y$. In a way, $e$ is the empty symbol, but one writes ‘$e$’ to visualise it.

Comment: Thanks for post but none of the $x^2, y^n, e$ are the elements of set $G$. And what is the group operation there?

Comment: If you consider  that writing  $x^2$ is writing  $y^n$ is $x^0y^n$, &c. There's no problem. The group operation is concatenation followed by simplification with the rewrite rules.

Comment: $x^0y^n$ but the power of $y$ is $n$ which is great than $n-1$. Could you show the whole solution because it is quite unclear?

Comment: @RFZ: I've added a proof of the first formula. Is that clear?

Comment: You wrote that $y^{-1}y^{1-j}=y^{-j}$ why this formula is true in set $G$? In general, why $y^{a}y^{b}=y^{a+b}$ is correct?

Comment: That's the law of exponents. If you don't assume it is valid, you can't make any computation.

Comment: I think that it should be proved i.e. it is valid on set $G$. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: Stop! The law of exponents is true in group. However our set $G$ is not yet a group. We should prove that $G$ is group. The following question arises: Why this law is true in our set $G$?

Comment: It is not only true in groups, it is true in monoids, and it is true anywhere you decide it is true, provided it is consistent with the other properties. Without it, you can't do much.

Comment: However, there is no nothing in my algebra book about that (only its correctness in groups).

Comment: How do you decide that, say, $y^2y=y^3$?

Comment: I do not know that because that was my question. Could you show in your answer why exponent laws is true in set $G$. It is one of the moments which I am not able to prove. I have spend too much hours for that problem however i have no results :(

Comment: I can't show it only with the properties in your question. The law of exponents has to be set as an axiom.

Comment: Do you some link where I can find the proof that set $G$ with given properties is a group. I am not able to prove that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is Problem 17 on p.54 in Herstein's book.

I don't like this problem.
The author didn't explain what "formal symbols" means.
The author didn't explain what the product between formal symbols is.
So, I am not sure that my answer is right.

I solved this problem as follows:

> (a) I have two questions about (a).
> Can we assume that $i,k\in\{0,1\}$ and $j,l\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$?
> Do $\alpha$ and $\beta$ need to satisfy $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$ and $\beta\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$?
> I don't assume that $i,k\in\{0,1\}$ and $j,l\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.
> I assume that $i,j,k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$.
> And I assume that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ need to satisfy $\alpha\in\{0,1\}$ and $\beta\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.
>
> Since $x^2=y^n=e$, we can assume that $i,k\in\{0,1\}$ and $j,l\in\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$.
> If $k=0$, then $(x^iy^j)(x^ky^l)=x^iy^jy^l=x^iy^{j+l}=x^iy^r$, where $r$ is the integer which satisfies $j+l=qn+r$ and $0\leq r<n$ for some integer $q$.
> If $k\neq 0$, then $k=1$.
> Since $xy=y^{-1}x$, $yxy=yy^{-1}x=x$.
> So, $yx=xy^{-1}=xy^{n-1}$.
> So, $y^jx=y^{j-1}yx=y^{j-1}xy^{n-1}=\dots=xy^{j(n-1)}$.
> Therefore, $(x^iy^j)(x^ky^l)=(x^iy^j)(xy^l)=x^i(y^jx)y^l=x^i(xy^{j(n-1)})y^l=x^{r_1}y^{r_2}$, where $r_1$ is the integer which satisfies $i+1=q_1 2+r_1$ and $0\leq r_1<2$ for some integer $q_1$ and $r_2$ is the integer which satisfies $j(n-1)+l=q_2n+r_2$ and $0\leq r_2<n$ for some integer $q_2$.
>
> (b) By (a), $G$ is closed under the multiplication.
> $(x^0y^1)(x^1y^0)=yx=xy^{n-1}\neq xy=(x^1y^0)(x^0y^1)$ by the assumption of Problem 17.
> If $x^iy^j\in G$, $(x^iy^j)^{-1}=y^{-j}x^{-i}=(x^0y^{-j})(x^{-i}y^0)\in G$ by (a).
> I guess it is obvious that the associative law holds.
> So, $G$ is a non-abelian group.
> The order of $G$ is $2n$ by the assumption of Problem 17.
>
> (c) **If $n$ is odd, prove that the center of $G$ is $(e)$, while if $n$ is even the center of $G$ is larger than $(e)$.**
> Suppose $n$ is an odd integer.
> Let $a$ be an element of $G$ such that $a\neq e$.
> If $a=x^0y^j$, then $1\leq j<n$ since $a\neq e$.
> $(x^0y^j)(x^1y^0)=x^1y^{-j}$.
> $(x^1y^0)(x^0y^j)=x^1y^{j}$.
> Since $2$ and $n$ is relatively prime and $j\not\equiv 0\pmod n$, $2j\not\equiv 0\pmod n$.
> So, $x^1y^{-j}\neq x^1y^{j}$ by the assumption of Problem 17.
> So, $(x^0y^j)(x^1y^0)\neq (x^1y^0)(x^0y^j)$.
> Therefore $a=(x^0y^j)\notin Z(G)$.
> Next, we consider the case in which $a=x^1y^j$.
> Then, $(x^1y^j)(x^0y^1)=x^1y^{j+1}$.
> And $(x^0y^1)(x^1y^j)=x^1y^{j-1}$.
> Since $2$ and $n$ is relatively prime, $2\not\equiv 0\pmod n$.
> So, $x^1y^{j+1}\neq x^1y^{j-1}$ by the assumption of Problem 17.
> So, $(x^1y^j)(x^0y^1)\neq (x^0y^1)(x^1y^j)$.
> Therefore $a=(x^1y^j)\notin Z(G)$.
> So, $Z(G)=(e)$.
> Next, suppose that $n$ is an even integer.
> Let $a:=x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}}\neq e$.
> Then, $(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})(x^0y^l)=y^{\frac{n}{2}+l}=(x^0y^l)(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})$.
> $(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})(x^1y^l)=xy^{l-\frac{n}{2}}$.
> $(x^1y^l)(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})=xy^{\frac{n}{2}+l}$.
> Since $2\frac{n}{2}\equiv 0\pmod n$, $(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})(x^1y^l)=(x^1y^l)(x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}})$.
> Therefore $a=x^0y^{\frac{n}{2}}\in Z(G)$.
> So, $Z(G)$ is larger than $(e)$.